# count the number of digits in a string

Tags: c

I need to implement a function that can count the number of digits in a string, and here is my code which is not working and i need to know what's the problem.
int main() {

```
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
char s[100];
scanf("%s",s);
int i,j=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    int freq=0;
    while(s[j] != '\0')
    {
        if(s[j] == i +'0')
        {
            freq++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("%d ",freq);

}    
return 0;
```

}

Comment: not resetting `j` to zero at each iteration is the issue. You could do this with only 1 loop with `s[j]-'0' < 10 && s[j]-'0' >= 0` test

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446042/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-digit-within-a-string for a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset `j` to 0 after each `for` loop iteration

Comment: it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: No probem, Nada.